# IF-THEN w/ strings in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, for-loop

I am trying to check if two cells values are equal to each other by reading in the value with strings. Using a for loop to step through to find the match of the IF-THEN statement.

When stepping through the program It shows that the values are equal at one point but the IF-THEN comparison just keeps running I can not figure out why it will not stop when they are equal.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lcol As Long
Dim Val As String
Dim Check As String

'Read in value for audit to continue

Val = ContTextBox.Value

'Make Master Sheet Active
 Worksheets("Master").Activate

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master")


'Finds next empty column

  With ws
        lcol = .Cells(11, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
  End With


'i needs to be set to minimum limit
'Begin loop of search

For j = 1 To lcol
    Check = Cells(11, j).Value

   If Check = Val Then

       Unload Me
       Assetlookup.Show

    End If

  Next j

Unload Me
```

Comment: Are the strings really completely the same? Sometimes, you get "invisible" chars along with others. For example, a `\r\n` won't be displayed,  but is part of the string

Comment: as @EngJon said the strings are not equal. you could stop the code and convert the two strings to ascii code or anything else and check them again.

Comment: You may want to trim the string from both the cells and then compare.

Comment: The values are dates. So there is a date in the worksheet that is "07/29/91" and then when the userform come up it asks for the date to search for, so I would then enter in the same date "07/29/91" . I watch it while stepping through in the 'Locals' tool bar and it shows they are the same visually but im not sure if it is carrying extra characters with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How 'identical' are the two strings? Is one capitalized and the other not? Does one have leading/trailing zeros? Does one have non-printable characters?

Try this, which cleans each term before comparing them:

```
If AllCleanedUp(Check) = AllCleanedUp(Val) Then
```

...

Which refers to the following function:

```
Function AllCleanedUp (DirtyString byVal) As String

    AllCleanedUp = Trim(Application.Clean(Lcase(DirtyString)))

End Function
```

Comment: The strings should be identical because they are just using  a date. So there is a date in the worksheet that is "07/29/91" and then when the userform comes up it asks for the date to search for, so I would then enter in the same date "07/29/91"

Comment: I ended up just using If Trim(check) = Trim(Val) Then and that worked