# vba delete rows based on multiple criteria - code is missing some of the criteria

Tags: vba, excel, criteria, delete-row

I have a vba code that deletes rows based on multiple criteria. It works very well and I like how short and simple the code is. However, I have noticed that it somehow misses some of the cells that contain the criteria. Typically just three or so of the listed criteria I would like deleted. Any clue why this may be happening??

Here is the code:

```
Sub DeleteMyRows()

Dim Rng As Range, Cell As Range
Set Rng = Range(Range("B2"), Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
For Each Cell In Rng

If Cell = "ADD" Or Cell = "ANFR" Or Cell = "CADV" Or Cell = "DEF" Or Cell = "DEFD" Or Cell = "OIL" Or Cell = "PROP" Or Cell = "STAX" Or Cell = "UREA" Or Cell = "WWFL" Or Cell = "NGAS" Then
    Cell.EntireRow.Delete
End If

Next Cell
End With
End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: My guess is that one of your cells contains, for example, "Add", which is not all uppercase like ADD; therefore it is not considered 'identical' to your search term. See my answer below which eliminates some common 'invisible' differences between text values.

Answer (score 0):

[Answer taken from a previous question here: [IF-THEN w/ strings in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31943667/5090027)]

How 'identical' are the two strings? Is one capitalized and the other not? Does one have leading/trailing zeros? Does one have non-printable characters?

Try this, which turns Cell into CleanedCell before using as a comparison:

```
CleanedCell = AllCleanedUp(Cell)

If CleanedCell = "ADD" Or CleanedCell = "ANFR" Or CleanedCell = "CADV" Or CleanedCell = "DEF" Or CleanedCell = "DEFD" Or CleanedCell = "OIL" Or CleanedCell = "PROP" Or CleanedCell = "STAX" Or CleanedCell = "UREA" Or CleanedCell = "WWFL" Or CleanedCell = "NGAS" Then
    Cell.EntireRow.Delete
End If
```

...

Which refers to the following function:

```
Function AllCleanedUp (DirtyString byVal) As String

    AllCleanedUp = Trim(Application.Clean(Ucase(DirtyString)))

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

it may be that the values in Cell are in a different case, or have leading or trailing spaces. (I often find this problem in manually input data)

try using:

```
If UCase(Trim(Cell.Value)) = "ADD" Or UCase(Trim(Cell.Value)) = "ANFR" Or ....... Then
```

Comment: Note that there could also be non-printable characters (such as line-breaks), which are not considered trailing spaces and cannot be 'trimmed'. Instead, you need the additional 'clean' function applied as well. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

It could be one of the orther answers, but my guess is that the problem is that when you delete a row, "cell" becomes the next one under and you then hit the "next" and skip this row completly. 
For exemple, if you do:

```
Sub test()
Dim cell
For Each cell In Range("A1", "A10")
    cell.EntireRow.Delete
Next cell
End Sub
```

You will only delete rows 1,3,5,7,9

You should loop in reverse, which as far as i'm aware is not possible with a for each cell in range(...) loop, but can be done by iterating over numbers like so:

```
for i=cells(rows.count,"B").end(xlup).row to 2 step -1
    If Cells(i,"B") = "ADD" Or Cells(i,"B") = "ANFR" Or Cells(i,"B") = "CADV" Or Cells(i,"B") = "DEF" Or Cells(i,"B") = "DEFD" Or Cells(i,"B") = "OIL" Or Cells(i,"B") = "PROP" Or Cells(i,"B") = "STAX" Or Cells(i,"B") = "UREA" Or Cells(i,"B") = "WWFL" Or Cells(i,"B") = "NGAS" Then
        Cell.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
next i
```

Comment: I agree fully with your comments, but I only add that you can actually work backwards with a For loop, by using the For statement: For x = MAX_VALUE to MIN_VALUE Step - 1 [Step + 1 is assumed; you can also do Step + 2 to only loop every other one, etc.]

Comment: Oh that's my bad, my comment on this was not very clear, what I meant is that (as far as I know) you cannot go backward if you use for each cell in range(...), but you can if you iterate over numbers. I will clarify it, thank you!

Comment: Ah right, you mean 'For Each' cant go backwards. So far as I know, that's not possible, so I agree with you again.

Answer (score 0):

i like to do :

```
If Cell LIKE "*ADD*" Or Cell LIKE "*ANFR*" Or Cell LIKE "*CADV*" Or Cell LIKE "*DEF*" Or Cell LIKE "*DEFD*" Or Cell LIKE "*OIL*" Or Cell LIKE "*PROP*" Or Cell LIKE "*STAX*" Or Cell LIKE "*UREA*" Or Cell LIKE "*WWFL*" Or Cell LIKE "*NGAS*" Then
    Cell.EntireRow.Delete
End If
```

the star (*) means any letters, numbers, spaces... can be before or after (in my example) your given values.

- this is case unsensitive, that's why i like it!

Hope this help.